# Objective c - SQLite selecting random row with another value

Tags: objective-c, select, random, sqlite

Basically I have a database of words,

This database contains a rowID(primary key), the word and word length as table columns.

I want to select a random row where length = x and get the word at that row.

This is for an iPhone game project and it is high priority that the queries are as fast as possible (the searches are made in a game).

For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM WordsDB WHERE >= (abs(random()) %% (SELECT max(rowid) FROM WordsDB)) LIMIT 1;
```

This query is really fast at selecting a random row a lot faster than ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1, however, if I add the word length to the query I get issues:

```
SELECT * FROM WordsDB WHERE length = 9 AND rowid >= (abs(random()) %% (SELECT max(rowid) FROM WordsDB)) LIMIT 1
```

Presumably because the random row will not always have a length of 9.

I was just wondering what would be the fastest / most efficient way of doing this.

Thanks for your time

Note: the 2 % symbols are because it is in objective c and the query is set as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to work ok for me:

```
select * from WordsDB 
where length = 9 
limit (abs(random()) % (select count(rowid) from WordsDB 
                        where length = 9)), 1;
```

note that `length = 9` appears in both `where` clauses.

Add index on `length` if it appears to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Add an index to the WordsDB.length

```
create index if not exists WordsDBLengthIndex on WordsDB (length);
```

should make selection on this field much faster